# NLog: update CSV structure after changes to config

Tags: csv, nlog, target, auto-update

Let's say I have the following NLog config:

```xml
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/nLog.csv" archiveAboveSize="50000000" archiveNumbering="Sequence" maxArchiveFiles="3">
      <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
        <column name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <column name="level" layout="${level}"/>
        <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
```

This config has been in use for some time and now I want to add another column, like this:

```xml
<layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
            <column name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
            <column name="level" layout="${level}"/>
            <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
            <column name="codeLine" layout="${event-context:item=codeLine}" />
</layout>
```

Problem: the existing *csv file is not properly updated (the new column is not added to the file). I can still log to the file, but the new column is ignored. 
Is there a way to get NLog to automatically update the file? Deleting the log file in order to have it re-created is not an option.

Comment: is autoreload enabled?

Comment: As @Julian said, check the auto reload.  It will not add the column header as that has been written. It will just add it to the next column on the line.

Comment: Correction: AutoReload is "true" in the config, that doesn't help. Calling "LogManager.Configuration.Reload(); manually also does not create the missing column.

Comment: codeLine being set in code?  The test app I wrote adds the string in the next column.  It does not add a new column header, just an entry in the next column on the line that the change started on. I can share the sample if interested.

Comment: Yes the "codeLine" is being set. I will check if the value is added for new enties (column header would be nice though).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use a custom variable. 
Update the config file to define the custom variable,

```
<variable name ="variable1" value =""/>
```

Then update the layout renderer with the variable,

```
<target name="csv" xsi:type="File" filename="filename">
  <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout" withheader="true">
    <column name="Column1" layout="${var:variable1}" quoting="Nothing"/>
  </layout>    
</target>
```

You can set the value of the variable from C# client,

```
LogManager.Configureation.Variables["externalDevice"] = "ValueOf_variable1";
```

Have you seen the github Wiki link [varlayoutrenderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer) relating to this concern.